# Why I get Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: 404'?

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I try catch exception, but i still get "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: 404' in C:\OS\OpenServer\domains\kinopoisk\parser\php\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php:69"

```
 <?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    set_time_limit(0);

    require "vendor/autoload.php";

    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
    use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
    use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

    $filmsUrl = [297, 298];

    $urlIterator = new ArrayObject($filmsUrl);

    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'http://example.com',
        'cookies' => true,
    ]);

    foreach ($urlIterator->getIterator() as $key => $value) {
        try {
            $promise = $client->requestAsync('GET', 'post/' . $value, [
                'proxy' => [
                    'http'  => 'tcp://216.190.97.3:3128'
                ]
            ]);

            $promise->then(
                function (ResponseInterface $res) {
                    echo $res->getStatusCode() . "\n";
                },
                function (RequestException $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
                    echo $e->getRequest()->getMethod();
                }
            );
        } catch (ClientException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            echo $e->getRequest()->getMethod();
        }
    }
    $promise->wait();
```

What wrong in my code?

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure, but you are catching `ClientException` only here. Try to catch `RequestException`, too. Looking at the code in `Middleware.php:69` that is the exception class used, but if you want to catch all exceptions, then you need to go for the most abstract exception class, which should be 
`RuntimeException` or `GuzzleException`.

Try something like this:

```
try {
    // your code here
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {
    // catches all kinds of RuntimeExceptions
    if ($e instanceof ClientException) {
        // catch your ClientExceptions
    } else if ($e instanceof RequestException) {
        // catch your RequestExceptions
    }
}
```

or you can try following approach

```
try {
    // your code here
} catch (ClientException $e) {
    // catches all ClientExceptions
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    // catches all RequestExceptions
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank for your feedback, it helped me understand where is my error. I think i don't understand what really makes the "$promise->wait()" =) because when I replaced it in my "foreache", then everything starts to work. Also when I put $promise->wait() in "try catch", it too work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  
  //some code
  
  try {
    $promise->wait();
  } catch (RequestException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

In the guzzlehttp requestasync method, the HTTP request is initiated when the wait method is called, not when the requestasync method or the then method is called. Therefore, you need to add try catch to the wait method